# Does the Dell Vostro 1720 support enabling Intel VT in the BIOS?

Tags: virtualization, vt-x, dell-vostro

After all the [problems that Sony VAIO owners encountered](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/08/06/sony_vaio_virtualization_disabled/) with not being able to enable Intel's VT support in the BIOS, does anyone know if Dell allow you to enable of VT mode in their Vostro 1720 BIOS?

I have a Vostro 1700 and it's supported, the model I'm considering buying has the Intel P8700 Core Duo processor which does have VT support. I just want to double check they haven't reversed this with the 1720.

I've looked everywhere on the Dell Support and Manuals site but can't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already this quiz at the [Dell community forum](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19302764.aspx), i recommend to contact Dell customer service. from my experience they're very helpful folks, even with technical details.

Vostro Support (UK) Technical Support Queries

Phone Number: 0844 338 1111

Hours: 8am - 6pm Monday - Friday

*[Source](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/topics/topic.aspx/emea/shared/support/dellcare/en/byphone_prod?c=uk&l=en&s=gen)*

HTH

Comment: I did and they seem to think it's ok. Ordered on my credit card and the Mail Order Protection scheme here means I've got 7 days to return the goods if not satisfied.

Comment: fingers crossed that it all work out well. :)

Comment: Laptops arrived and all is good :) VT capability is enabled.

Comment: i'm delighted for ya :)